# standard normal distribution for very small Z

Tags: probability, statistics

So I have to find the "i" from the following

$P(S_i=X_1+X_2+X_3+..+X_i < 1680 ) = 0.95$

for N(84,28)

And I have found that $E(S_i)=i*84$ and $V(S_i)=i*(28)^2$

What I did :

$$P\left(\frac{S_i-E(S_i)}{\sqrt(V(Si) }\right) <  \left(\frac{(1680-i*84)}{√(i*(28)^2)}  \right)=1-0.05 <=>
P(z< \left(\frac{1680-i*84}{√(i*(28)^2) }\right) = 1 - 0.05$$

and now  the value from z-table for $φ(z)=0.05$ does not exist. Is there a rule for small values in z-table?

Comment: are you sure you want an equality ?

Comment: $P[Z<1.644854] \approx 0.95$

Comment: @Thomas where do you mean exactly?

Comment: @JohnL yes but shouldnt I have done the "1-0.05" part? because according to you i dont have to find the z for φ(z)=0.05 but the z for φ(z)=0.95..

Comment: You want an i making that quantity exactly equal to 0.95 ? When I tried it seemed to me that such an i does not exist. I may be wrong of ciurse but just checking. Maybe you want an inequality?

Comment: @Thomas i had the same problem actually thats why i cannot find it... So you think the methology i did is right?